# WSDL URL is accessible from browser but not from java program

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, proxy, wsdl

I have a web service running on a remote server and I wrote a client program to consume its services. The client program uses client stubs that were generated from a .wsdl file using the wsimport command. I am accessing the server via a proxy and in my program I tell the JVM to communicate via the proxy by setting the system properties "proxySet", "proxyPort" and "proxyHost", to true, and the corresponding port and address of the proxy respectively; which works fine. In addition, I'm also connecting via SSL, and the server certificate is signed by some other CAs, and in my case I needed to import the certificate to the trustore cacerts; which also works well. However I am not able to access the web service with the URL I specify in my program, though it can be accessed with a browser. below is the stack trace of my program:

```
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:     https://webservicesimp.companyName.com/ReportingService
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://webservicesimp.companyName.com/ReportingService?wsdl

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.conpanyName.xml.companyName.enterprise.report.v1.enterprisereportingservice_1.ReportingService.<init>(ReportingService.java:50)
at WebServices.<init>(WebServices.java:33)
at ERSWebServiceRunner.main(ERSWebServiceRunner.java:37)
```

Any help is appreciated... Thanks

Comment: First, simplify the situation by taking JAX-WS out of the equation.  Does `HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://webservicesimp.companyName.com/ReportingService?wsdl").openConnection(); System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());` display 500?

Comment: Right... In fact I have two different URL; one without the parameters like: https://webservicesimp.companyName.com/ReportingService, and the other with parameters like: https://webservicesimp.companyName.com/ReportingService?wsdl. For the one without parameters I get a response code of 500 and with the parameters, I get 404. Below is the code I run to get the HTTP responses

Comment: `URL url = new URL("https://webservicesimp.companyName.com/ReportingService");
       HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
          connection.connect();
       System.out.println("Response code: "+ connection.getResponseCode());
       System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());`

Comment: 500 means an error occurred on the server side.  If you have access to that server’s logs, I would check them for the error.  Also, if you have access to Unix or Linux or Cygwin, I would try using wget (with the `--content-on-error` option) or curl to retrieve the URL;  perhaps the response body will reveal some detail.